# D3Tip inconsistency in tip placement

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, tooltip

I've been working with D3 and D3tip for a few weeks now, and recently I've discovered an inconsistency in the display of tips (a question concerning the same topic has been posted and went unanswered before, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32492325/bootstrap-popover-tooltip-display-inconsistency?rq=1)).

My example:
I've built a responsive stacked barchart using D3Tip, and the tips display just fine:
[image: example]

However if I move to the right, some tips start to display oddly. They suddenly move further to the left than the offset `([-height/35, 0])` that I've declared:
[image: example]

I'm unable to reproduce this consistently, the only similarity I can find is that it only happens on the right side of the graph (similar to the previously asked question linked above).

I've checked my CSS and I can't find anything that's restricting the tips from being displayed there (I've tried changing the overflow property, the position and the margins even, the right margin seems to solve this for *the first time I hover on the rightest most bar, entering from the right*. I find this result very hard to interpret). Could it be that something within the library is causing this to happen? I'm far too inexperienced to start changing things in there, but I'm curious to see if someone knows a workaround that will allow me to keep the current design.

Thanks for taking a look!

For reference:
The code for the D3tip in my JS is as follows:

```
var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-height/35, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return /*TEXT*/;
  });
```

with the event calling it being:

```
.style("opacity", 1)
.on('mouseover', function(d){
            d.color = color(d.name);
            d3.select(this).style("opacity", 1);
            tip.show(d);
          } )
          .on('mouseout', function(d) {
            d3.select(this).style("opacity", 0.6)
            tip.hide(d);
          } );
```

and the CSS of the tip and 'pointer':

```
.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: .8em;
  padding: 12px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
}

.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}
```

The CSS of the div containing my chart:

```
#chart {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  font-size: .8em;
  font-weight: lighter;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 98%;
  height: 50%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  overflow-y: visible;
}
```

Update: This has been tested on Safari and the bug doesn't occur there.

Comment: Would be beneficial if you created a working example, JSFiddle for example

Comment: I'll have to get on that tomorrow afternoon, hopefully I'll be able to recreate the problem in JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This proved to be a troublesome thing to fix. The workaround I've used now is removing the d3tip: after portion of the CSS. Now the tip no longer 'points' to the bar that's being hovered over, making this bug irrelevant. I realise this is not the best option, but it's no longer worth the time investing into why this occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding below code to place the tooltip at the mouse pointer.

```
.style("left",  (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
.style("top",  (d3.event.pageY) + "px");
```

`Below is the proper code:`

Define a `div` with `id` `tooltip`:

```
    var div = d3.select("#toolTip");
    // if there is a div id="toolTip" already in body.Else append div as stated below.


    var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
            .attr("class", "tooltip")               
            .style("opacity", 0);
```

Add below code to your `svg`:

```
svg.on("mouseover", function(d) {       
  div.transition()      
  .style("opacity", .9);        
  div.html("Some Key: " +  d.value+"<br/>")
  .style("left",  (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
  .style("top",  (d3.event.pageY) + "px");  
  }).on("mouseout", function() {
    div.transition()        
    .duration(500)      
    .style("opacity", 0); 
    });
```

`CSS:`

```
div.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #f4f4f4;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    pointer-events: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #000;
    line-height: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}
```

Comment: I tried this yesterday but I didn't get it to work. I'm going to set up a JSFiddle for it, perhaps that'll prove to be more insightful.

Comment: @Yoeri . I edited my answer `var div = d3.select("#toolTip");` this line would only work if there is already `toolTip id ` existing but if not then add the alternate code mentioned in the above answer.

Comment: Thanks for trying @SiddP. I've been trying to recreate the bug using plnkr in the past hour and I haven't succeeded yet. I've decided I'm just going to remove the triangle pointing to the UI element that you're hovering over, that way it'll remove the awkwardness of visibly 'pointing' to the right direction without removing much of the original design. If you want to try around with the example feel free to do so at http://plnkr.co/edit/D3LMaqPCcK7x2gEgIDQb(that's not quite working as in the pictures above, but it should be enough to get started. I can't recreate the bug there though..)

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying though! It seems this is a case of 'let's do it differently instead of spending the day on trying to fix this'.

Comment: @Yoeri Well as per above answer it is not using d3.tip() but simple css work to display tooltip which has fared well for me try it once replacing with the logic you have tried.

Comment: If I've got time in the upcoming week I'll try it still. For now I'm content with removing the triangle. Thanks again!